# Using Terraform list of strings as an array in Shell template script

Tags: bash, shell, terraform

So, basically I want to be able to iterate in my Bash script template file over the array, that I initialise in Terraform.

The template file is used as `user_data` for AWS instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "my_instance" {
    
...

  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/${var.template_file}",
    {
      my_array    = ["item1", "item2"]
  })

...

}
```

Here is my template file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf "%s\n" "$${my_array[@]}" > my_array.txt
```

And when I execute `cat my_array.txt` it gives me no content.

I can know that workaround might be to define `my_array` as a string and after that parse it in Bash to an array, but I curios whether is it possible to avoid that and get kinda native variable interpolation here.

Any help or hints will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmmm. Seems like it's impossible yet. The shortest solution would be to pass the array as a string in the following way:

```
my_array    = join(",",["item1", "item2"])
```

and use that source to init required array:

```sh
IFS=',' read -r -a bash_array <<< "${my_array}"
printf "%s\n" "$${my_array[@]}" > my_array.txt
```

now your array's items should be listed in the file.